# .On event in Jquery on a div

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

```
<div id="multiaccount"></div>
```

How can I tie a method to the above div id, so that method gets called on the page where above div id is present?

I tried with below code, but it did not worked:

```
$(document).on('event', '#multiaccount', function() {
    somedivOnPage('false', ''); 
});
```

I am using `jquery-190.js` and `jqmobile-130.js`.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you need to define the `event`

Comment: There is no native event named `event` in JQuery. Use an existing event like click, hover, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the jQuery **ready** method is triggered when the page finished to load. At this moment, the length property will return 1 if your div exist on the page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    if($('#multiaccount').length > 0)somedivOnPage('true', '');
    else somedivOnPage('false', '');

})
```

Comment: Thanks this is working , now i need  to do additonal research and testing to make sure this will not break anything else.

Comment: Please, don't forget to indicate which answer was the good one!

Answer (score 0):

Is the function you are referencing to valid, or defined, in the page?

When I tested your code on a Fiddle, it worked:

```
<div id="multiaccount">Hello</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('click', '#multiaccount', function() {
    alert("click() event fired");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/ZKMhD/

Comment: The OP wants an event triggered if the div is present, not necessarily clicked.

Comment: @Gabe I was trying to illustrate that there is nothing inherently wrong with his code, by using click as an example event.

Comment: I am looking for any event other than click , so that the method calls when page loads? sorry for confusion

Comment: @Terry, that is more of comment rather than an answer then.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you want something like this

```
 $('#multiaccount').bind('customevent', function () {
 if ($('#multiaccount').is('visible')) {
// code goes here
 }
 })
 $('#multiaccount').trigger('customevent');
```